# How to add a % right before and after a function returned value in MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make our search module be able to search keywords like *lex. Using * to substitute the letters before that. I found the % I add into my query doesn't work and returns error. Please help me to have a look at my code. thanks

```
if(substr($searchfirst_name, 0, 1) == '*'){
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE %".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name);
}elseif(substr($searchfirst_name, -1, 1) == '*'){
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE ".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name)."%";
}else{
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE ".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name);
}
```

I think the problem is because of the function Formatter::sql(). It filter the variable and add slash to it. How do I modify or create a new function to do this?

```
public static function sql($value, $fieldName = false) {
if($fieldName) {
  return '`' . $value . '`';
}
else if( is_string($value) ) {
  return '\'' . addslashes($value) . '\'';
}
else if($value === null) {
  return 'NULL';
}
else if($value === true) {
  return 1;
}
else if($value === false) {
  return 0;
}
else if( is_numeric($value) ) {
  return $value;
}
else {
  return '\'' . addslashes($value) . '\'';
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a link to `Formatter::sql` documentation or the code for it? You'll need to see if it has another parameter to not automatically include quotes.

Comment: My guess is the error is something like: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use quotes I think:
`LIKE '%...'` or `LIKE '...%'`

**EDITED:**
Well, the error is clear now:
query run using formatter is like `.... LIKE %'....'` which is completely wrong.
When you use `LIKE` clause don't use formatter, but use `$searchfirst_name` directly!!

Comment: @AlexHu: can you show us the ouput of `Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name)` please?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I edit my question, please have a look

Comment: I know that, but that would cause a big security hole to SQL injection

Comment: @AlexHu: rewrite part of Formatter.sql command to include LIKE syntax, it's pretty easy. You can use another param in function definition and another if in the body to create correct syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(substr($searchfirst_name, 0, 1) == '*'){
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE '%".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name)."'";
}elseif(substr($searchfirst_name, -1, 1) == '*'){
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE '".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name)."%'";
}else{
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE '".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name)."'";
}
```

Comment: Can you store result of Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name) in a variable then try to place it in query.

Answer (score 0):

The first two look ok, but your third else cannot be LIKE. See below.

```
if(substr($searchfirst_name, 0, 1) == '*'){
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE %".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name);
}elseif(substr($searchfirst_name, -1, 1) == '*'){
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE ".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name)."%";
}else{
  $subquery .= " AND first_name = ".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
if(substr($searchfirst_name, 0, 1) == '*'){
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE ".Formatter::sql('%'.$searchfirst_name);
}elseif(substr($searchfirst_name, -1, 1) == '*'){
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE ".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name.'%');
}else{
  $subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE ".Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name);
}
```

This will work because the escape functionality in `Formatter::sql` won't affect teh '%'

In your `sql` function, replace `addslashes` with the database provided escape function, e.g., [mysql_real_escape_string](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Always use the database mechanism for escaping strings (or better yet, use parameterized queries with PDO).

Answer (score 0):

You had an % outside of string quotes and you probably need to get rid of * characters too

So instead of whole if contruct:

```
$subquery .= " AND first_name LIKE ".str_replace('*','%',Formatter::sql($searchfirst_name));
```

but beware this gives the functionality to substitute * everywhere in the string